# How to add Options to a List

Tags: scala, collections

What is the best way to add `Option`s to a `List`.

Here is my first try :

```
def append[A](as: List[A], maybeA1 : Option[A], maybeA2: Option[A]) : List[A] = as  ++ maybeA1.toList ++ maybeA2.toList
```

Con : it creates 2 tmp `List`

(I know .toList() is optional because there is an implicit conversion from Option[A] to Iterable[A])

Another try is

```
def append2[A](ls: List[A], maybeA : Option[A]) : List[A] = maybeA.map(_ :: ls).getOrElse(ls)
def append[A](as: List[A], maybeA1 : Option[A], maybeA2: Option[A]) : List[A] = append2(append2(as, maybeA1), maybeA2)
```

Better perf but less readable…

Is there another way ?

Comment: Why do you want to add an Option[A] to a List[A]. Surely you want to see if there is something worth adding?

Comment: Don't add to the end of a list.

Comment: Yeah, I hate to be that guy on Stack Overflow, but if you're finding yourself appending to the end, it's worth asking: Is there actually a reason you're using `List` here (rather than some other type of sequence)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def combine[A](s: Seq[A], o: Option[A]) = (s /: o)(_ :+ _)
def combineAll[A](s: Seq[A], os: Option[A]*) = (s /: os)(combine)

combineAll(List(1), Some(2), None, Some(3))
//res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Or, for brevity:  `(s /: os)((l, o) => o.fold(l)(l :+ _))`

Comment: @BenReich thanks, i put the idea in it. It may look like a magic tho

Answer (score 8):

Use `List.++` or `List.++:` :

```
def append[A](o:Option[A],l:List[A]):List[A] = l ++ o   
def prepend[A](o:Option[A],l:List[A]):List[A] = o ++: l
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you please add a bit of explanation to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use mutable list builder

```
val builder = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[A]
builder ++= list
builder ++= maybe1
builder ++= maybe2
...
builder.result()
```

It can give performance improvements if you have a lot of options to add, closer to thousands, I think on smaller number original solution should be good

Answer (score -3):

1. You can't add `Option[A]` to `List[A]`. You have to either use `List[Option[A]]` and then adding an option is fairly trivial, or for every option you have to check if it indeed holds something (`Some(a: A)`) and add it to the list only then.
2. If the order of the elements in the list is not very important, at least not during the adding phase, then it would be the best to add them at the beginning, instead of the end, using the `::` operator. Adding elements to the beginning of a list takes constant time. Adding them at the end takes **O(n)** where **n** is the number of elements already in the list. That's because the program has to first traverse the whole list from the beginning to the end and only then can add the new element.

So, the answer to your question will be either:

```
def add[A](ls: List[Option[A]], maybeA : Option[A]) = maybeA :: ls
```

or

```
def add[A](ls: List[A], maybeA : Option[A]) = maybeA match {
  case Some(a) => a :: ls
  case None => ls
}
```

And then, after adding all elements you like, you can just call `ls.reverse` to have them in the order you would have if you were appending them.

Comment: Yes you can add `Option[A]` to `List[A]`. Just fire up a REPL and paste this code: `List(1,2,3) ++ None ++ Some(4) ++ Some(5) ++ None`
This works exactly the same as your second solution, but is much more nicer.
Also calling `ls.reverse` will reverse your original list as well which isn't intended.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that mistake with `case None => ls`. But.
1. The author didn't say anything about the context. That's why I first wrote "if the order is not important", because maybe it isn't and we can use `::` which is faster. Besides, this adding an option to list with `++` ... well, it doesn't really add an **option**. It adds **A** or nothing :)

Comment: 1. A `List` by definition is ordered, so providing a solution that messes up the order is, in my book, incorrect. 2. The question provided two examples of what the author meant on "adding an option to a list" and if you would have tried them out you could see that they indeed are "add A or nothing".